# How can I debug this thread related error

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a large project, when I press a button I start a task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    CreatePortfolio();
});
```

The form has an MSChart and I have a delegate for each method that access the chart.

When I step through code NO ERROR is thrown. But when I just run it I get this error - but do not know where it originates from as it is display on Application.Run line below:

```
public static string[] MainArgs;
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    MainArgs = args;

    Application.Run( new MainForm( ) ); //ERROR shown here
}
```

And the Exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Years value must be between +/-10000.
Parameter name: years
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=years
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTime.AddYears(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHelper.GetIntervalSize(Double current, Double interval, DateTimeIntervalType type, Series series, Double intervalOffset, DateTimeIntervalType intervalOffsetType, Boolean forceIntIndex, Boolean forceAbsInterval)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHelper.GetIntervalSize(Double current, Double interval, DateTimeIntervalType type, Series series, Double intervalOffset, DateTimeIntervalType intervalOffsetType, Boolean forceIntIndex)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.FillLabels(Boolean removeFirstRow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Put try-catch block, and show exception.ToString(), you can see the line number where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Any chances you're dealing with weird dates? See *Years value must be between +/-10000*

Comment: Try catch - doesn't catch it... That's why I think it thread related

Comment: Stack doesn't tell me where this is happening

Comment: See [How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.110).aspx) and check for `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the dialog box

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work in a multi-thread environment. Or perhaps it is because the error occurs within mscharts.repaint, but I get not trace of WHAT it is repainting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using DateTime.AddYears at some point and value passed to add years is not valid.

please check i think you are using some array and passing values from some index of that array and at one point passed not available in array. This is your problem

Comment: No it not coming from AddYears in MY code. But it could be from within mscharts when it's repainting the page